# boost filesystem canonical path is not valid after conversion to const char *

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

I am trying to transform a relative path and convert it to absolute to pass to SQLite using boost filesystem. This is supposed to work correctly for windows and linux

```
    boost::filesystem::path path("../../data/dominion");
    boost::filesystem::path file("dominion.db");
    boost::filesystem::path canonical = boost::filesystem::canonical(dataPath / file);
```

canonical returns

```
   m_pathname=L"D:/Users\\me\\Documents\\tonkatsu\\data\\dominion\\dominion.db"
```

As you can see the beginning of the path "D:/" is not correct. I also tried to call normalize() on it without success

Is there a way to remedy to this ?

Comment: Despite not being standard practice, forward slashes can also be used in many parts/libs on Windows. Have you tried actually passing that path?

Comment: passing that path to sqlite3_open returned an error but you are correct, if I use that path in explorer, the path is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite not being standard practice, forward slashes are also accepted on Windows, that's why boost isn't forcing the conversion.

However, some libraries won't accept forward slashes. [`boost::filesystem::path::make_preferred()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-make_preferred)<sup>[1]</sup> is meant to solve such situations, by converting the path to the system's *preferred* representation (i.e. using backslashes on Windows).

[1] [This older reference makes that behaviour more obvious](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-make_preferred)

As discused below, while (most of) the Windows API accepts forward slashes, and even a mixture of forward and backslashes, some user interfaces even on applications included in Windows don't.

Comment: forward slashes aren't accepted on windows, what makes you think so? Try to open notepad and try to open filepath with forward slashes. It's the runbox that seems to be fixed up to handle forward slashes, and windows itself doesn't. The other point: boost::canonical actually breaks normal path into invalid one. If I pass to it valid windows paths that POS turns first slash into forward slash. WHY!?

Comment: basically fwd slashes aren't universally supported, which makes these path with fwd slashes invalid

Comment: @pavel experience makes me think so. Notepad is not Windows; the Windows API does accept forward slashes, the fact that some applications and libraries don't allow them shouldn't fool you. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx. And as noted above, Boost does provide a way to enforce backslashes.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I tried to call winapi and it does work and make_preferred fixes up messed up path with first forward slash in drive letter. So far my greatest annoyance is that file open dialog (which is also winapi) doesn't seem to like forward slashes in paths